# jQuery/PHP - detect which button is pressed

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making some app (admin page), I loaded all users in `<table>`, also I have option to activate and deactivate each user. Now my problem is I don't know how to detect which 'activate' or 'deactivate' button is pressed, my code only works for first user in list. This is my code:

adminPage.php:

```
<?php
$getData = $mysqli->query("select * from login");
while($row = $getData->fetch_assoc()):
?>
<tr id="dataRows">
    <td id="firstTd"><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['active']; ?></td>
<?php if($row['active'] == 1){ ?>
    <td><label id="userID" hidden><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></label>
    <label id="userActive" hidden><?php echo $row['active']; ?></label>
    <label id="optionLabel"><?php echo 'Deactivate'; ?></label></td>

<?php } else{ ?>
    <td><label id="userID" hidden><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></label>
    <label id="userActive" hidden><?php echo $row['active']; ?></label>
    <label id="optionLabel"><?php echo 'Activate'; ?></label></td>

<?php } endwhile; ?>
```

script.js:

```
$("#optionLabel").click(function(){
            $.post("option.php", {"id" : $("#userID").html(), "com" : $("#userActive").html()},
                function(data){
                    if(data == "Updated"){
                        window.location.href = "adminPage.php";
                    }
                }
            );
    });
```

Comment: You can't have multiple ID's.

Comment: Well, I have more then one "optionLabel" buttons. My code only works when I click on first one. Since all buttons have same atributes I need to detect on which one I press so I can deactivate and activate apropriate user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

//adminPage.php

```
  $getData = $mysqli->query("select * from login");
                while($row = $getData->fetch_assoc()):
        ?>
        <tr id="dataRows">

                <td id="firstTd"><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['active']; ?></td>
                <?php if($row['active'] == 1){ ?>

                            <td><label class="userID" hidden><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></label>
                            <label class="userActive" hidden><?php echo $row['active']; ?></label>
                            <label class="optionLabel"><?php echo 'Deactivate'; ?></label></td>
                        <?php } else{ ?>
                            <td><label class="userID" hidden><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></label>
                            <label class="userActive" hidden><?php echo $row['active']; ?></label>
                            <label class="optionLabel"><?php echo 'Activate'; ?></label></td>

            <?php } endwhile; ?>
```

//script.js

```
$(".optionLabel").click(function(){
            $.post("option.php", {"id" : $(this).siblings('.userID').html(), "com" : $(this).siblings('.userActive').html()},
                function(data){
                    if(data == "Updated"){
                        window.location.href = "adminPage.php";
                    }
                }
            );
    });
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you. And also I would like to know why my quesition id downvoted. If I can't find solution for my problem it's natural to ask help from someone else.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I'm new to stackoverflow as well :)

Comment: I know, thank you. I was addressing to that person who downvoted my question.

Comment: Happy to help, if you could accept my solution that would be awesome :D

Comment: @Alen Hi. I did NOT downvote you (just for the record). To somewhat answer your question as to why your question was downvoted could be, that you did not show/mention what it is that you have tried, or the effort you put in to fix it yourself; "the proof is in the pudding", as it were, and many think that you could be asking a question just to get some (free) code. Since you are new to StackOverflow, and welcome by the way, you should read the "help" section. Many answers can be found in there, that may help you in the future.

Comment: @AlvinNguyen Welcome to StackOverflow as well Alvin. Just a quick and friendly word of advice when giving answers. When answering questions, it is always better to let the OP (original poster) know, as to where he/she went wrong and to point out the errors that were made; an explanation *as it were* as to how the code works and back it up with actual facts (*the proof is the pudding*) also (wink). Some will downvote perfectly good answers, just because of that. Just thought you should know that. You'll get the hang of it. All the best, cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change your ID's to classes (because ID's need to be unique).

If you have done that I would do this (I have changed your `#optionLabel` to `.optionLabel` and `#userID` to `.userID`:

```
$(".optionLabel").click(function(){
        $.post("option.php", {"id" : $(this).prev('.userID').html(), "com" : $("#userActive").html()},
            function(data){
                if(data == "Updated"){
                    window.location.href = "adminPage.php";
                }
            }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work better
use this:

//adminPage.php

```
<?php
                $getData = $mysqli->query("select * from login");
                while($row = $getData->fetch_assoc()):
        ?>
        <tr id="dataRows">

                <td id="firstTd"><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['active']; ?></td>
                <?php if($row['active'] == 1){ ?>

                            <td><label id="optionLabel" onclick="updatestatus(<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>, 1);">Deactivate</label></td>
                        <?php } else{ ?>
                            <td>
                            <label id="optionLabel" onclick="updatestatus(<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>, 0);">Activate</label></td>

            <?php } endwhile; ?>
```

//script.js

```
    function updatestatus(id , status){
var ac_id = id;
var ac_st = status;
            $.post("option.php", {"id" : ac_id, "com" : ac_st},
                function(data){
                    if(data == "Updated"){
                        window.location.href = "adminPage.php";
                    }
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Hidden Element Are Removed
and Statics value like 'active' and 'deactive' not printing